# Qual a diferença entre define() e const?

Tags: php, constantes

Qual é a diferença entre declarar constantes com `define()` ou com `const`.

Seria a mesma coisa ou tem algum detalhe que eu deveria saber?

```
define('TESTE', 'constante 1');
const TESTE2 = 'constante 2';

echo TESTE . '<br>' . TESTE2;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ambas podem ser usadas para definir constantes globais para a aplicação.

- `const` define a constante em tempo de compilação, que costuma ser bem melhor.

  Também pode ser usada para definir constantes com escopo de classe, que também é bem melhor.

  Como não é possível definí-la em tempo de execução, ela não pode ser criada condicionalmente como é possível com `define`. Há uma técnica de programação (ruim, na minha opinião) que se beneficia da existência ou não de constantes.

  Obviamente algumas expressões não são possíveis na definição de uma `const`, apenas o que pode ser resolvido em tempo de compilação.

  Como o nome de uma `const` deve ser defino em tempo de compilação, o nome não pode ser gerado à partir de alguma expressão.

  O nome é sensível à caixa já que é um símbolo da linguagem.

  É mais rápido acessar uma constante real que um elemento de um dicionário.

  É elegante, é como outras linguagens fazem, parece o certo, é mais legível, provoca menos confusão.
- `define` define a constante em tempo de execução. No fundo ele cria uma chave em um dicionário para armazenar um valor.

Sempre que possível eu prefiro `const`. E para falar a verdade sempre é possível. Pra mim `define` ficou como legado. Só na versão 5.3 do PHP `const` pode ser usado para definir constantes globais. Mas como o ideal é não definir nada global, sem pelo menos ter um escopo, já não fazia diferença.

Documentação de [`const`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php) e [`define`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Interessante! Já ia fazer essa pergunta. Vejo muitos projetos, para versões recentes do PHP, com um monte de chamada para `define`. Creio que fica até melhor para organização do código

Answer (score 6):

Isso foi respondido nesta pergunta aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447791/define-vs-const

Mas o geral mesmo é que até o PHP 5.3 você não podia usar o **const** dentro do escopo global, ele era restrito para escopos de objetos (uma classe por exemplo). Ele servia para definir uma variável constante local dentro do escopo deste objeto.

O define tem o mesmo propósito, mas ele só pode ser usado em escopo global, e o uso dele deve ser apenas para setar configurações globais que vão afetar a aplicação como um todo.

Os exemplos de **const** e **define** variam bastante, por exemplo, o **const** pode ser usado dentro de uma classe matemática para armazenar o valor de um número pi, por exemplo, já que ela só será alocada quando o código compilar.

Já o **define** pode ser usado para setar um parâmetro global da aplicação, um skin por exemplo, ou alguma configuração do sistema que precise ser lida por todo o código. Já que ela é criada em tempo de execução você não terá problemas se o código não passar por aquela parte.