# Valor de constante em todo o projeto

Tags: php

Estou utilizando um projeto estruturado PHP

***index.php***

```
<?php      
  require 'vendor/autoload.php';  
  $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv( "C:/env" ); 
  $dotenv->load();
  define('VARIAVEL', getenv( 'NOME_DA_VARIAVEL' ));
  echo VARIAVEL."<br>";
  echo "<a href='1.php'>a</a> ";    
?>
```

***1.php***

```
<?php
  echo VARIAVEL;
?>
```

Gostaria que a variável constante definida no index servisse para todo o projeto

Comment: Só vai 'adicionar' ela a outros arquivos através do `include/require`

Comment: No orientado a objetos não precisei dar o include ou require

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença entre define e const?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45806/91)