# Diferença entre global, const e define()

Tags: php, variáveis, constantes, variáveis-globais

Então estava estudando sobre POO e estruturas MVC com o PHP e vi que muitas vezes precisamos usar variáveis globais (acessíveis durante toda a aplicação) e qual a diferença de usar:

```
global $nome = 'Joao';
define(NOME,'Joao');
const NOME = 'Joao';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`global` declara uma **variável normal** com [escopo e tempo de vida global](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) (não é só local onde foi declarada), portanto ela existe por todo o tempo da execução desde o momento de sua declaração. Isto por si só já mostra como pode ser problemático, porque em algum lugar pode acessar algo que não foi declarado. Existem outros [problemas relacionados a estado global](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21158/101). Na forma como as pessoas usam PHP deveriam evitar ao máximo. Se usassem como *script* que seria o certo a fazer em uma linguagem de *script* então variável com esse escopo não seria tão problemática assim já que tem pouco para observar e consegue manter mais controle.

O resto da pergunta pode ser verificada em pergunta já feita antes até porque nada tem a ver com variáveis: [Qual a diferença entre define() e const?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45806/101), ambas não variam e são globais.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, ajudou muito.